# Prove if $AB=BA$ then rankA=rankB

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that if matrices $A,B$ are such $AB$ and $BA$ are defined, furthermore $AB=BA$ then rankA=rankB.

My try: I have problem with proving this since I think this statement can be false since if we consider $\left[\begin{array}{ccc}1&0\\0&1\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{ccc}1&0\\0&0\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}1&0\\0&0\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}1&0\\0&0\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{ccc}1&0\\0&1\end{array}\right]$ and we have rankA $\neq$ rankB

Comment: .. that gives you a counterexample (and saves you the time to search for non-existing proof).

Comment: I suggest editing the question to: Find the conditions under which such defined matrices have the same rank.

Comment: @ Mario , you are not super !

Comment: $0 I = I 0 = 0$. The problem, as stated, couldn't be more wrong.

Answer (score 2):

This is false, indeed. Another simple example is to take $A=\mathbb{I}_n$ (identity $n\times n$ matrix) and $B=\mathbb{0}_n$ (zero $n\times n$ matrix).

More generally, this choice of either $A$ or $B$ shows that most of the statements of this form will be wrong: for any $n\times n$ matrix $C$, using either $A$ or $B$ you can find a counter-example (if $\mathrm{rank} C > 0$, use $B$; otherwise, use $A$).

Answer (score 1):

Proof by non-example is perfectly acceptable. When you ask for a proof, you might just get a proof that there is no proof!